# How can I suppress a "bubble" from Beamer heading using Frankfurt template?

Tags: beamer, navigation

Is there some way to repress creation of a bubble displayed in the Frankfurt progress header for specific frames?  In the example below, when compiled it will show four bubbles on the top of the ticker.  Instead I'd like for there to only be two bubbles one for Slide 1 and another for Slide 2a, but to suppress bubbles for slides 2b and 2c.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Frankfurt}}
\begin{document}
\section{Intro}

\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{Slide1}
    Text
\end{frame}

\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{Slide2a}
    Image
\end{frame}

\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{Slide2b}
    Image
\end{frame}

\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{Slide2c}
     Image
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you should rather fix the "jumping" of the images. Could you provide an example demonstrating the behavior? (You can use demo images provided by the graphicsx package)

Comment: Yes, I edited out that first part because it seemed like a separate question.  I might post it separately.

Comment: I posted the separate question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332166/how-do-i-prevent-images-from-shifting-on-separate-overlays-of-same-slide

Answer (score 1):

Very simple: Just don't start a new frame.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Frankfurt}}
\begin{document}
\section{Intro}

\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{Slide1}
    Text
\end{frame}

\subsection{}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle<1>{Slide2a}
    \frametitle<2>{Slide2b}
    \frametitle<3>{Slide2c}
    \only<1>{Image1}
    \only<2>{Image2}
    \only<3>{Image3}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, yes, I was trying this initially, but for some reason, the images "jump" between overlays (so going from <1> to <2> the image will shift locations even though it is the same code and the same sized image).  Figuring out how to stop that jumping is a separate question.  But I'd really just like to know if it's possible to suppress the bubble for a frame itself.

Comment: @SRH Then please update your MWE to show this jumping problem.

Comment: I will post this as a separate question since I am still interested to know how to suppress bubbles for specific frames.  Thank you

Comment: @SRH but the suppression of the bubble I showed you a link, doesn't that answer your questioN?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Yes.  I apologize, I missed your link.  That solves the issue.  Thank you!